# How do I equip hats?

Tags: toejam-and-earl-back-in-the-groove

After completing Toejam & Earl: Back in the Groove for the first time I earned a hat.  When I started my next game, said hat wasn't equipped.

How do I equip my new hat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can randomly equip a hat at the start of each level after level 1. Sometime it won't equip a hat as a blank is part of the randomness.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a hat nearby the starting point, laying on the ground or hidden in bushes (it marked with sparkles).

Comment: This doesn't explain how to equip a hat.

Comment: @pinckerman did you ever played this game before minusizing me?
You don't have any "select the hat menu" here! And no "equip" button, it's not an RPG. You have to find a hat and touch it to equip, on each level. Is it more clear explanation?

Comment: Don't get upset, I gave you a suggestion. You only explained **where** to find a hat, not **how** they work. You should add that comment to the answer which is definitely clearer. I only pointed it out, it wasn't me to downvote your post.